# how to get two rows from a table using join

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my code

```
 $query = $this->db
        ->select('*')        
        ->join('users as receiver', 'receiver.user_id = messages.user1')
        ->join('users as sender', 'sender.user_id = messages.user2')
        ->get('messages')->result_array();
```

this is database

```
users table 
user_id |username | datetime
  1     | abc1   | 000000000
  2     | abc2   | 000000000

messages table
msg_id | user1 | user2 | msg   | timestamp
  1    | 1     |  2    | hello | 000000000
```

i want to get records of two users as sender and receiver. but this join give me record of last join. in this case i m getting record of sender.
 i want output like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [user1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [username] => abc1
                [datetime] => 2016-11-07 03:00:00
            )

        [user2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [username] => abc2
                [datetime] => 2016-11-07 00:00:00
            )

        [message] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [message] => hdf
                [timestamp] => 2016-11-06 08:43:26
            )

    )
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share `users` and `message` table structure and data (by updating your question) ?

Comment: sure updated... i m unable to fetch receiver and sender data at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SQL to create a union query that will give you two rows

```
select * from messages m join users u on u.user_id = m.user1 union all select * from messages m join users u on u.user_id = m.user2;
```

or with a join statement for two users in one row

```
select * from messages m join users u1 on u1.user_id = m.user1 join users u2 on u2.user_id = m.user2;
```

Comment: query is not missing it is working fine. if u don't want to write "from(messages)" u can write it in "get(messages)" it works same. yes i m using codeigniter. Union also not working... your code giving me same result...

Comment: i might b wrong in getting data. i m using print_r($query->result_array();

Comment: I assume you mean print_r($query->result_array()); just checking your not missing a bracket in your code.

Comment: Try running this query in your mysql client

select * from messages m
    join users u on u.user_id = m.user1
    union all
    select * from messages m
    join users u on u.user_id = m.user2;

It gives me two rows. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: it is running for two rows but i need it in one row only which should contain user1 data, user 2 data and message data. i m unable to fetch two users data in one row.

Comment: i need the result that i have asked in my question. please see my question again if u can any help me.... i might be wrong in my logic. if you have some better idea please share with me. and thanks a lot for trying helping me.

Comment: If you want both users in one row then use a join like this select * from messages m join users u1 on u1.user_id = m.user1 join users u2 on u2.user_id = m.user2;

Comment: it is the same as in my question.

Comment: Not sure what your asking. I have recreated your two tables on a MySQL server and have run the sql join I showed you. That produces one line with both users referenced. Just run that SQL in MySQL client and it will work, assuming that your DB structure is the same as you have put in your question.

Comment: Ok let me explain again. my messages table has two user ids. user1 and user2. i just want when i fetch data from messages table it should also give me data of both users so that i can get their names. suppose i have message_id=1 which contains user1_id=1 and user2_id=2. When i call data of message_id=1, it gives me user1_id=1 and user2_id=2. I just want it should also give me data of both users in same row. same as i required in my question.

Comment: The join statement I gave you works on my server. I re created the tables you defined in your question and that SQL works, by returning one row that contains the message and both users. What error do you get when you run that SQL?

Comment: i get only one user data. which have is in last join

Comment: oh yes your query is running on my server too. but when i try this query in model like this                $query = $this->db->query("select * from messages m 
                join users u1 on u1.user_id = m.user1 
                join users u2 on u2.user_id = m.user2")->result_array();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($query);
        die;

Comment: i get response ....................     [0] => Array
        (
            [msg_id] => 1
            [user1] => 1
            [user2] => 2
            [message] => hdf
            [timestamp] => 2016-11-06 08:43:26
            [user_id] => 2
            [username] => abc2
            [datetime] => 2016-11-07 00:00:00
        )